# C# Speech Recognition Library not able to recognize dictation of "nonsense words"

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, speech-synthesis

I am using "System.Speech.Recognition" and "System.Speech.Synthesis" libraries from C# to create a small speech synthesis windows application.

The app works fine with words fed in its grammar and recognizes but fails to recognize other words. ( like "zapssss Hello zapssss" , which is not actually a proper phrase). Help on this section required. I am a complete newbie to C#.

The code portion is as follows:-

```
   public string[] get_data_list() 
    {
        int counter = 0;
        string line;
        string[] data_list = new string[8];
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\\Users\\usr\\Desktop\\Voice Recognition\\Voice Recognition\\data_dict.txt");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            data_list[counter] = line;
            System.Console.WriteLine(data_list[counter]);
            counter++;
        }

        file.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        Console.WriteLine(data_list);
        return data_list;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Choices commands = new Choices();

        string[] voice_dict = get_data_list();

        foreach (string arrItem in voice_dict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arrItem);
        }

        commands.Add(voice_dict);
        GrammarBuilder gBuilder = new GrammarBuilder();
        gBuilder.Append(commands);
        Grammar grammar = new Grammar(gBuilder);
        recEngine.LoadGrammarAsync(grammar);
        recEngine.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        recEngine.SpeechRecognized += recEngine_SpeechRecognized;
    }

    void recEngine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e) 
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Entered Event");
        string[] voice_dict = get_data_list();
        string msg;
        string user_recorded_voice = e.Result.Text;
        string voice_check_flag = check_voice_available(user_recorded_voice, voice_dict);

        switch (voice_check_flag)
        {

            case "not found":
                System.Console.WriteLine("Match Not Found for " + user_recorded_voice);
                msg = ("\nText " + user_recorded_voice + " Not Recognized");
                text_box.Text += msg;
                synth.SpeakAsync(msg);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("\nMessage recieved " + voice_check_flag);
                text_box.Text += voice_check_flag;
                synth.SpeakAsync(voice_check_flag);
                break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why do you expect the speech recognition to recognise nonsense words? I'd expect it will only recognise what it can recognise.

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft you'll only be able to detect the text from speech which you trained your system for (Using Grammar) [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh361683(v=office.14).aspx)

Though it has different event That you can look into

[SpeechRecognitionRejected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognizer.speechrecognitionrejected.aspx)

[SpeechDetected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognizer.speechdetected.aspx)

> But as of now you can't know what user has spoken outside of your
>   trained grammar set.